# SQL GROUP BY to count the amount of rows rather than a sum of the amounts

Tags: sql, group-by

I am trying to Group by to get  count 1 if there is more than one in a category for a widget in a country.

To explain it better, here is the code that i have got so far:

```
select c.Name As Country, w.Description As WidgetName, cat.Description As Category,
  COUNT (wc.Id)AS Clicks  
  from ManufacturerWidgets mw
 join WidgetClicks wc on mw.Id = wc.ManufacturerWidgetId
 join Products p on   wc.ProductId = p.Id
 join Countries c on mw.CountryId = c.Id
 join Widgets w on w.Id = mw.WidgetId
 join Categories cat on cat.Id = p.CategoryId
 where mw.Enabled = 1 and  mw.ManufacturerId = 17 and wc.CreatedAt >= '2013-01-01 00:00:00.000' and wc.CreatedAt <= '2013-07-05 23:59:00.000'
 GRoup By wc.WidgetImpressionId, c.Name,  w.Description,  cat.Description
 HAVING wc.WidgetImpressionId > 0
 order by  c.Name, w.Description, cat.Description
```

This returns for example:

```
County   WidgetName   Category    Clicks

Austria  onebysix     computing   1
Austria  onebysix     computing   4
Austria  onebysix     printing    1
Austria  onebysix     printing    3
Austria  onebysix     printing    2
```

What I need to return is the inteeraction for each category so:

```
Austria  onebysix     computing   4  - this would be 1 not 4
```

and i need to group them by the category so the end result would be:

```
Austria  onebysix     computing   2
Austria  onebysix     printing    3
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove `wc.WidgetImpressionID` from the GROUP BY. This is adding the extra level of grouping which happens to be the count for the desired result

Change the `COUNT` to `COUNT(wc.WidgetImpressionID)` to give 2 and 3 respectively

The HAVING should be `HAVING COUNT(wc.WidgetImpressionID) > 0`. In your code, it acts like a WHERE clause filter because it is in the GROUP BY (see my first point above)

```
select c.Name As Country, w.Description As WidgetName, cat.Description As Category,
  COUNT (wc.WidgetImpressionID) AS Clicks  
  from ManufacturerWidgets mw
 join WidgetClicks wc on mw.Id = wc.ManufacturerWidgetId
 join Products p on   wc.ProductId = p.Id
 join Countries c on mw.CountryId = c.Id
 join Widgets w on w.Id = mw.WidgetId
 join Categories cat on cat.Id = p.CategoryId
 where mw.Enabled = 1 and  mw.ManufacturerId = 17 and wc.CreatedAt >= '2013-01-01 00:00:00.000' and wc.CreatedAt <= '2013-07-05 23:59:00.000'
 GRoup By c.Name,  w.Description,  cat.Description
 HAVING COUNT(wc.WidgetImpressionID) > 0
 order by  c.Name, w.Description, cat.Description
```

Comment: Hi gbn that seems to be adding the clicks together - so for computing I'm getting 5 and for printing i'm getting 6 rather than 2 and 3 am I missing something?

Comment: Without sample data we can only guess. Try `COUNT(DISTINCT wc.WidgetImpressionID)` instead